# Migrating to Places 4.0 SDK, how to migrate place Bias?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I am migrating to the new places SDK 4.0

The old func was:

```
findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: query,
                            bounds: bounds,
                            boundsMode: .bias,
                            filter: filter,
                            sessionToken: token) { (prediction, error) in
                                        callback(prediction, error)
}
```

the new func as per docs is

```
findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: query,
                            filter: filter,
                            sessionToken: token) { (prediction, error) in
                                        callback(prediction, error)
}
```

I see that bounds bias is now set on the `GMSAutocompleteFilter` filter

This has a `locationBias` property where i set `some` and it takes a parameter of `<GMSPlaceLocationBias>`

The issue i have is there is no info on what to provide here...`GMSPlaceLocationBias` is a protocol, and i have no idea what im meant to use object wise to provide the old bounds data.

Conforming to the protocol gives me a `locationBiasURLQueryItem` fun to populate, with no further documentation on what should go in this function

So im stuck and cant upgrade as there doesnt seem to be a clear way forward.

Anyone have any ideas? Docs are here: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client#ab60773feec0e68751c5a7f1066b9d252)

My attempt to construct the filter is:

```
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    if case .location(let location) = _locationController.locationStatus {
        filter.locationBias = .some(location)
    }
```

But obviously my custom location model object doesnt confirm to GMSPlaceLocationBias and is a struct so cant be used and errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got totally lost on this as well, but just found an example buried in one of the guides [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#biasing_results_to_a_specific_region).

In short the implementation looks like this:

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.locationBias = GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(bounds.northEast, bounds.southWest)
```

Here I'm using the same bounds I had previously been using in 3.x (in my case from the map currently being displayed) to get those northEast and southWest coordinates, but you can generate your own based on how where you are trying to bias results.

I wish they had just made ANY indication in their docs that this was the intended way to do it.

Comment: ah yes got it working now, shocking documentation to not draw attention to the use of this new class! thanks for pointing it out hopefully this question helps others upgrade too

Comment: Can you guys find any reference or documentation for GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption? cause i see no where in both Map SDK or Places SDK.

Comment: @NeihPaine330 it is in the same header file as the declaration for `locationBias`. It is declared:
```objc
FOUNDATION_EXTERN id<GMSPlaceLocationBias, GMSPlaceLocationRestriction>
GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(CLLocationCoordinate2D northEastBounds,
                                  CLLocationCoordinate2D southWestBounds);
```

Comment: it does not work for me, I am setting the north and south bounds properly but then the result is not working. For instance, look for a place that is 100 meters from my location and shows one that is more than 50 km first in the list, if I search same query in google maps it shows the right one. any advice? 
I've check north and south coordinate in google maps and looks accurate for the 7km rect I want to have.